# Woocommerce Not Showing Product Title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, title

Can anyone help me figure out whats going on with the title of single product page not showing?

I know its a theme issue, because I tried with another theme and it was showing the title normally.

I tried add some code into functions.php but it didnt work.

The site I need help with is: https://ciadaborracha.com/produtos/plasticos/pvc-cortinas/cortina-pvc-verde/

Maybe someone with more knowledge than me can inspect and see if its missing something.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I checked your theme demo and documents apparently, your template does not support woocommerce, since it doesn't mention nether in the document nor woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We have checked your website the title is not showing up because of the highlighted CSS on the screenshot.

Comment: You rock! It worked! But deleting this CSS shows a search box in the top-left corner. Its visible now in website if you want to view and inspect. Do you know if there is a easy way to remove this?

Comment: .ablog__text--title4 {
    display: block!important;
}

Add this in your css.